# Getting System.Net.Sockets.SocketException while accessing RavenDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, ravendb

Recently I've installed `RavenDB` (a bunch of assemblies: client, database, embedded) thru `NuGet` package manager. I have configured `DocumentStore` like this:

```
public override void Load()
{
    Bind<IDocumentStore>().ToMethod(
        context => {
            var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { 
                Url = "http://localhost:8080", 
                DefaultDatabase = "ampDatabase",
                UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
            };
            return documentStore.Initialize();
        }
    ).InSingletonScope();

    Bind<IDocumentSession>().ToMethod(context => 
        context.Kernel.Get<IDocumentStore>().OpenSession()
    ).InRequestScope();
}
```

After this code is called:

```
documentSession.Store(idea);
documentSession.SaveChanges();
```

I'm getting `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`:

> No connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set things up like this:

```
 var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { 
                Url = "http://localhost:8080", 
                DefaultDatabase = "ampDatabase",
                UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
            };
```

The problem is that this actually tells us to NOT use embedded mode, but to try to things in a server client manner.
Change it to be:

```
 var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { 
                DataDirectory = "Database",
                UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
            };
```

And it will work